# JTable filter using two (2) JDateChooser

Tags: java, netbeans, filter, jtable, jdatechooser

I have 2 jdatechooser, one is datefrom and the other one is dateto. I want to filter my jTable data within the range of those two jdatechooser. My problem is whenever I try to filter the table (with dates within the range of my jdatechoosers), my table becomes empty.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");

        String from = (String) sdf.format(txt_datefrom.getDate());
        String to = (String) sdf.format(txt_dateto.getDate());

try {
                String sql = "select reference, name, date, time, totalAmount, "
                        + "discount, status from receipts where date "
                        + "between '" + from + "' and '" + to + "' ";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table_audit.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                total();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: **1)** What is happening when you pass the DATE in the format "MMM d, yyyy" to your DB? **2)** When did you saw (last time) the window, or site with *two* Date Choosers? Your goal can be accomplished with single one...

Comment: I haven't seen any post about two jDateChooser yet. :-/

Comment: It is not about how many `JDateChooser`s you will use in your app. I simply suggest to use the single one. But, point of your question is *What looks like the string in my DB table which represent the DATE?*

Comment: The date looks like Mar 11, 2018

Comment: what is the output of:
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
        String from = sdf.format(new Date("Mar 11, 2018"));
        System.out.println(from);`
**BTW, Date is deprecated**!

Comment: I fixed it. I just changed all the date and its formats to yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Well done. Good luck, friend